# Renaming Razor pages in asp.net Core 2 Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm starting a new project using asp.net Core 2 with Identity, and would like to change the Razor pages `Register.cshtml` and `Register.cshtml.cs` pages to `Signup.cshtml` and `Signup.cshtml.cs`. However, after doing so, the page will show validation errors but will not submit and I cannot hit a breakpoint in the `OnPostAsync`. Is there something going on "under the hood" that prevents this from working?

Comment: I suspect this doesn't have anything to do with Razor Pages at all. It seems to be a client-side issue. Perhaps some broken JS. Something is actually preventing the submit button from working properly. You might even just have a client-side validation error that's not exposing a validation message, so you can't tell there's actually an error.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt, some bad Javascript was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

After scaffolding Identity to your project , rename the `Register.cshtml` to `Signup.cshtml` won't work since the `Register` button will still redirect to `/Identity/Account/Register` , which is controlled by Identity RCL after renaming .

You can modify the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` , and change the link to :

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Signup">Register</a>
```

So that it will use the `Signup` page .